# How to keep the Editor activated and keep executing "Update()" offscreen (when I use another software)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use Unity Editor to perform some ScreenShot job.

I put the modification logic of my object inside the *Update()* and a *ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot()* will be performed inside *LateUpdate()*. It works fine, the object is updating normally and a ScreenShot will be produced for each update.

I'd like to keep this process working "in the background", that is, even if i'm using another software, it will keep executing this rendering-screenCapture flow. However, the script doesn't work at all when the Unity window is inactivate.

Any ideas? How can I keep the Editor updating offscreen? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I noticed that there's *Run in Background* toggle in *Edit-Project Settings-Player-Resolution*, I've no idea what it actually does, but nothing seems to be affected when I toggled it on.

Comment: I manage to keep the process running in Play mode by setting *Application.runInBackground = true;*. It seems that *Run in BackGround* works only during game play.